# Adding new function to window.event say 'stopPropagationAndPreventDefault'

Tags: javascript, jquery

To stop default action and propogation of event on any click handler I use:

```
function something(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

I was wondering if this could be optimized as :

```
function somethingnew(e) {
    e.stopPropagationAndPreventDefault()
}
```

which intern executed the logic of something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do **not** recommend this, but it can be done by modifying the prototype of Event object. Thus the function `stopPropagationAndPreventDefault` can be invoked directly on an event instance.

```
Event.prototype.stopPropagationAndPreventDefault = function(e) {
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

See the snippet below:

```js
Event.prototype.stopPropagationAndPreventDefault = function(e) {
  alert("Function called");
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
  }
};

var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

function clickHandler(e) {
  e.stopPropagationAndPreventDefault();
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Maybe show (also) an alternative if this isn't recommend?

Comment: For what they are trying to do, I can only think of this one way, i.e. modifying the prototype. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe a wrapper around `event`?

Comment: @Julian I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you add an answer?

Comment: Thank you. But curious on, why not recommended?

Comment: Modifying the prototype of event might interfere with something the browsers might want to support at a future date. For example, if the browser introduces a function `stopPropagationAndPreventDefault` later on, your code will overwrite that.